# Javascript Jumping Physics

Tags: physics, javascript

I have asked questions for this project before, but the jumping physics are a bit messed up. I cannot jump unless I hold down the W key, and then it just teleports me upwards. Does anybody know how to fix this glitch? Here's the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            var x = 1
            var y = 0
            var xPos = 0
            var yPos = 0

            function updateVariables() {
            x = x * 0.9
            y = y * -0.9
            y = y + 0.5
            xPos += x
            yPos += y
            }

            function clear() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600)
            }

            function Draw() {
            collisionCheck();
            clear();
            ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,10,10)
            ctx.fillRect(0,canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7,600,200)
            window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw)
            }

            function collisionCheck() {
            if (yPos > canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7 - 10) {
                yPos = canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7 - 10
            }
            }

            function right() {
                x = 2
            }

            function left() {
                x = -2
            }

            function jump() {
                y =+ 20
            }

            function detectKeys() {
                document.onkeypress = function (e) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    console.log(e.key)
                    if (e.key == "d") {
                        right()
                    }
                    if (e.key == "a") {
                        left()
                    }
                    if (e.key == "w") {
                        jump()
                    }
                }
            }
            

            window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw)
            setInterval(updateVariables, 1)
            setInterval(detectKeys, 1)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="140"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

A glaring math problem pointed out by DMGregory is that you're multiplying your `y` position by `-0.9`, meaning it's oscillating between positive and negative. That's probably a good brunt of why jumping doesn't work, even ignoring the other problems below.

A few other problems, most JavaScript/Web specific:

First, your `detectKeys` doesn't at all do what you think it's doing. It's just registering a callback on `onkeypress`. It won't actually read any keys at that time. The event handler will get triggered when a key is pressed. And since you're re-registering this over and over again via `setInterval`, you're registered multiple handlers, which will all get called whenever a key is pressed. You just want to register the handlers once at the beginning of the game and never again; the callbacks will be invoked when a key is pressed so there's no need to keep polling. The callback will be called only when the key state is triggered (I'll address that below).

Second, `document.onkeypress` isn't what you want anyway. It is triggered when you first press the key and is automatically repeated based on the browser's/OS's key repeat rate. You want to use `onkeydown` instead.

Third, and going back to how you're using the callbacks, you're only applying movement when the key is triggered (first pressed, or on the key repeated rate because you're using `onkeypress`). You want to store the input state (e.g. whether the player is trying to move left/right or is trying to jump) and apply that state, rather than directly responding to keyboard events. This means using `onkeydown`/`onkeyup` to update some state variables and then reading those state variables in your game loop.

Fourth, you have a typo in `jump`. You wrote `y=+20` instead of `y+=20`. What you wrote is equivalent to saying `y=(+20)` or just `y=20`.

Finally (from what I see in a quick perusal), the way you're trying to do the game loop is wrong. You have `draw` correctly keyed to `requestAnimationFrame`, but your `updateVariables` should be as well. `setInterval` is not a good function to use in general for this kind of stuff, because the interval is non-reliable (it might be more or less frequent than requested or be skipped periodically, etc.). Make just a single `update` function that is scheduled via `requestAnimationFrame`, and then have this `update` function call your `updateVariables` function and then the `draw` function. You'd also insert a new function here that reads those keyboard state variables and applies the requested movement. I'd further add that you want to use a time delta (because you can't predict the framerate that `requestAnimationFrame` will run at) when applying your physics/movement code so that you get smooth and predictable movement; you can calculate a time delta via the `performance.now` call.

I'd highly recommend that you read over some tutorials like https://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-game-foundations-the-game-loop/ and https://codeincomplete.com/posts/javascript-game-foundations-player-input/ (perhaps that whole series) which will cover all these topics with code samples.

Comment: The repeated flipping of `y = y * -0.9` looks questionable too...

Comment: Hah, nice catch, I totally didn't even notice that one. :) Will update answer with that note.

Answer (score 0):

For just fixing the jumping you only need to change a few things. I put a comment in the code wherever I changed something. There are other things that could be nice to change, but you only asked to fix the jumping so here it is. Good luck with your project!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var x = 1
var y = 0
var xPos = 0
var yPos = 0
var onGround = false; // keep track if you're on the ground, so you cant jump mid-air
function updateVariables() {
    x = x * 0.9
    // y = y * -0.9  // removed line because it did many weird things with the y velocity
    y = y + 0.05 // changed from 0.5 to 0.05 otherwise it went back down way too fast
    xPos += x
    yPos += y
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600)
}

function Draw() {
    collisionCheck();
    clear();
    ctx.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 10, 10)
    ctx.fillRect(0, canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7, 600, 200)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw)
}

function collisionCheck() {
    if (yPos > canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7 - 10) {
        yPos = canvas.offsetHeight * 0.7 - 10
        onGround = true; // new line
        y = 0; // set y speed to 0 when you hit the ground
    }
}

function right() {
    x = 2
}

function left() {
    x = -2
}

function jump() {
    if (onGround) { // check if you're on the ground before jumping
        // y =+ 20 // old code removed because y is negative in the up direction
        y = -2; // set y velocity to a negative number to jump up.
        onGround = false; // make so you cant jump again mid-air
    }

}

function detectKeys() {
    document.onkeypress = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        console.log(e.key)
        if (e.key == "d") {
            right()
        }
        if (e.key == "a") {
            left()
        }
        if (e.key == "w") {
            jump()
        }
    }
}


window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw)
setInterval(updateVariables, 1)
setInterval(detectKeys, 1)
```